# G Suite Integration using Marketplace SDK - Disable "Drive UI Integration" permanently

Tags: google-drive-api, gmail-addons, gsuite-addons

I enabled a Gmail Addon in a GCP project using the Markeplace SDK.

Afterwards I tried to add a Drive UI Integration as well.
Filling out the Form "*Drive UI Integration*" in the Google Drive API settings enabled the Drive integration. But it added a disabled "Drive extension" checkbox to the Marketplace SDK Configuration page and is now showing an error message "A gmail add-on can't be bundled with other extension type." and the Gmail Addon is not working anymore.

I did not find any way to remove the Drive UI Integration. Even disabling the Drive API does not revert this and makes the (internal) published Gmail Addon unusable. How can I delete/disable the Drive UI Integration and set the Markeplace SDK Configuration back to "Gmail add-on extension" only?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

### You can disable drive UI integration by

- going to the [developpers console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com)
- selecting the project of interest at the top left
- Selecting from the list of APIs the `Google Drive API`
- Clicking on the left menu on `Drive UI integration`
- Uncheck all checkboxes and click on `SUBMIT`, see image:

[image]

You can also disable the `Drive API` for the given project completely.

> However, when it comes to an Add-on - if the Add-On has been defined
>   as a Drive extension, I fear that you won't be able to reverse it.
>   Instead, you need to create a new project and publish a new Add-on,
>   rather than fixing the problematic one.